# Issue with updating app and issues with IOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, ios-simulator

I recently updated the some minor changes on my app, when i run simulator. It shows the correct UI contents. But when i run the app, same project everything it shows the old contents?

Can you anyone give me some feedback on fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try saving the code and restarting xcode?

Comment: Are you saying that it works properly on the simulator, but not on a real device?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? But try cleaning the build: cmd+shift+K